# Pycharm isn't working properly

Tags: python, pycharm

my pycharm isnt working properly, It doesn't highlight any syntax, doesn't show suggestion even doesn't change color of comments, Please tell me how to fix this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLBX.png)

Comment: `Test` doesn't appear to have an extension (e.g. `Test.py`). Is that the case?